# How can I create an HTML page that depends on form inputs?

Tags: python, html, forms

For starters - I am using a combination of HTML, Python+Flask/jinja

I have an HTML page which contains a basic form. When users input data to that form, it is passed through my Python/flask script and populates a different HTML template with the inputted form values.

What I need to accomplish is creating variations of the final HTML template based on what fields users choose in the beginning form. e.g.

The flow would appear as:

User selects fields to use in HTML form > data is passed through flask app > data is populated in final HTML template, which is designed around the fields selected in the original form.

The final HTML template is essentially a series of tables. Based on which fields the user selects in the form, some tables will be needed and others not.  Whether the user selects a field should determine whether or not the table appears in the final HTML templates code or not.

I'm not entirely sure what tools I can use to accomplish this, and whether I will need something to supplement flask/jinja. Thanks for any input.

Comment: you would need to know a bit of php aswell

Comment: @RachelGallen why on earth can the original poster not do this in Python?  PhP is irrelevant afaik to his approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask+Jinja should work well for what you're trying to do. Essentially, your first page would be a form with a number of form elements. When your form is submitted, that data gets passed back to your flask app where you can extract the users selections. Using these selections you can generate/populate the next html page.

Since the user can seemingly select any combination of fields, the template for your second html page should contain all the possible tables and then only show the selected ones using an `if...else` statement

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like exactly what I was looking for. I'll still probably struggle through getting it together, but I appreciate you sending me in the right direction!

Comment: :) Feel free to post more questions on specific issues as you start working on it. SO is here to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of server side code language to achieve this.

I'm going to show the answer in php, you can look into other methods as well to find the one right for you.

```
if ($_GET['foo'] == '1') {
    // This will be shown if the url is /file.php?foo=1
} else if ($_GET['foo'] == '2') {
   // This will be shown if the url is /file.php?foo=2
} else {
   // This will be shown if foo is not 1 or 2 or is not set.
}
```